# Why is one Visual Studio # include file of two not found?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino

Using Visual Studio 2017 with the VMicro plugin for Arduino.
Trying to include a constant data block in the compiled code. Include as Audio.h works, Audio.csv gives an error:

```
TestInclude.ino: 9:21: fatal error: Audio.csv: No such file or directory
```

Both include files are in the project folder, added to the solution and are readable by the Visual Studio editor.
I would like to use the .csv method, in my actual code there will be several and larger audio clips. What am I doing wrong?

Minimal example TestInclude.ino

```
#include "Audio.h"
const float Beep[] =
{
#include "Audio.csv"
};
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

File Audio.h

```
const float aaa[] =
{
0.00000,
0.05012,
0.10004,
0.14957,
0.19851,
0.24667,
0.29386,
0.33990,
0.38460,
0.42779,
0.46930,
0.50897,
0.54663
};
```

File Audio.csv

```
0.00000,
0.05012,
0.10004,
0.14957,
0.19851,
0.24667,
0.29386,
0.33990,
0.38460,
0.42779,
0.46930,
0.50897,
0.54663
```

[image: Solution explorer]

Comment: @SidS  Thatmissing semicolon  is an editing mistake, I will fix it. .h .csv and .ino are in the same directory.

Comment: @SidS Yes, I have read access. All files involved can be read and modified by the VS2017 editor.

Answer (score 2):

The INO files are not compiled directly. The [Arduino Build process](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process) describes that a CPP file is created in a temp directory. Header files are copied to that directory. But the CSV is not detected as a project file.

To workaround you can add a absolute path to the CSV file in the INO file.

It is not necessary to have the CSV list in a file with the ".csv" extension. You can also just add a ".h" at the end of the file name to get it copied to the temp directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround, if I rename `Audio.csv`to `Audio.csv.h` the include file is accepted.

I can live with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can set include path by right-clicking a project and go to:

```
Properties/VC++ Directories/General/Include Directories
```

Add the directory to Audio.csv